# How to add values to merge tag list variables in tinymce in react.js

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

**Introduction:**
I'm relatively new to using the TinyMCE editor in a React.js project and currently facing a challenge. I need to pass the entire content from the TinyMCE editor, including any merge tags used within it, through an API. Additionally, I want to keep track of these merge tags for future use.

**Current State:**
I have successfully integrated TinyMCE into my React.js project, and I can retrieve the content from the editor. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to identify and extract the merge tags and keep track of them.

How can I efficiently extract merge tags from the content within the TinyMCE editor?

```
    function Tinymce() {
      const editorRef = useRef(null);

      const handlerBtn = () => {
        if (editorRef.current) {
          console.log(editorRef.current.getContent());
        }
      };

      return (
        <>
          <Editor
            onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
            init={{
              selector: 'textarea',
              plugins: 'mergetags ',
              toolbar: ' mergetags ',
              mergetags_prefix: '${{',
              mergetags_suffix: '}}',
              mergetags_list: [
                { id: 145, value: 'First Name', title: 'First Name' },
                { id: 678, value: 'Last Name', title: 'Last Name' },
                { id: 987, value: 'Email', title: 'Email' },
              ],
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={handlerBtn}> Save </button>
        </>
      );
    }

    export default Tinymce;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.